# Why is typedef GLXContext required?

Tags: c, opengl

When creating an OpenGL context in C, it seems that I must declare a typedef for `GLXContext` such as the one below:

```
typedef GLXContext (*glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)(Display*, GLXFBConfig, GLXContext, Bool, const int*);
```

What exactly does this typedef do and why is it necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't typedef `GLXContext` you typedef a pointer to a function that returns a GLXContext and takes the parameters `(Display*, GLXFBConfig, GLXContext, Bool, const int*)`.

This typedef then can be used to actually define a pointer variable to such a function, which subsequently can be used to store the function pointer to said function queried using glXGetProcAddress. This function in turn is required for creating OpenGL contexts with a specific version.

Comment: I had to read this a few times to make sense of it, but I understand now. Thanks for the detailed answer.